# OpenCV- captured video runs faster than real time?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I am using openCV to capture video from camera and store to and avi file, the problem is that when i finish capturing and run the avi file, the video stream looks awkwardly fast...

here is the code

```
int isColor = 1;
 int frameW  = 640;
 int frameH  = 480;
 int fps     = 25;

 CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
 assert( capture != NULL );

 cvNamedWindow( "Webcam", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

 CvVideoWriter *writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
   "out.avi",
   CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),
   fps,
   cvSize(frameW,frameH),
   isColor
  );

 IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

 while( (frame = cvQueryFrame( capture )) != NULL ) {
  cvWriteFrame(writer, frame);
  cvShowImage("Webcam", frame);
  char c = cvWaitKey( 33 );
  if ( c == 27 ) break;
 }
```

i dont understand why when i use cvGetCaptureProperty(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS )  on Windows 7 32bit or 64 bit and Vs2008 & OpenCV 2.3.1, this funcition allway return 0, it is false, please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

cvSetCaptureProperty and cvGetCaptureProperty does not always work. Also, have you tried fps = 30?

It is also worth noting that you need to play your video at the same fps as your capturing fps.

Comment: how do fix the video stream looks awkwardly fast, if i tried fps = 30, it will run very fast, i just want it run like realtime

Comment: Have you tried fps=15 and fps=60? Does it make a difference at all?

Comment: yeah, i understanded, i combined successfull, i use Commanline: ffmpeg.exe -i 1.wav -i 1.avi -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.avi but it have 1 issue is: after combined, when i play video then audio & video not sync, example: sounds occurring before the video show, how to sync audio & video record ??

Comment: I believe that would be a ffmpeg question, you can post a separate question on that.

Comment: I thought we have already answered your question, if not, can you update your question to reflect what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue that cvGetCaptureProperty does not work properly, unless cvQueryFrame is called beforehand.

Comment: no, it still fail, this is my code: cvQueryFrame(camera);
 double xxx = cvGetCaptureProperty(camera,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS ) ;